# which regression is better

Tags: regression, algebraic-curves

suppose that we have two input  vector  and  the variables in each  vectors are  independent and  uncorrelated from each other,just only   there is relationship between two vector,but not itself in each  vector's variable,let say

```
x=rand(1,10);
>> x

x =

  Columns 1 through 9

    0.8147    0.9058    0.1270    0.9134    0.6324    0.0975    0.2785    0.5469    0.9575

  Column 10

    0.9649

y=10.*x+15

y =

  Columns 1 through 9

   23.1472   24.0579   16.2699   24.1338   21.3236   15.9754   17.7850   20.4688   24.5751

  Column 10

   24.6489
```

that means that  variables inside  $x$ are uncorrelated,but $y$ and  $x$ are correlated,my question is which regression analysis is related to this problem?

```
plot(x,y)
```

[image]

does it means that linear regression is best?

Comment: What statistical problem are you trying to solve? I'm having trouble understanding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regression procedure aims to find the most suitable parameters for the following problem:
$$
(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)\ \mbox{s.t.}\ F((x;\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n))\approx f(x),
$$

where $F(\cdot)$ is the regression function and $f(x)$ is the function that you want to approximate.

Therefore, since you shown a "perfect" linear relation between $x$ and $y$ you may want to use
$$
F(x;\alpha,\beta)=\alpha x+\beta.
$$

The goodness of fit will be measured by $\rho^2$, coefficient of determination.

Moreover, be aware that even if you'd had a parabolic relation, i.e. $y=ax^2$, you could have used:
$$
x^*=x^2,
$$
and your relation would have been
$$
y=ax^*,
$$
so that you could have used a linear regression function again (be aware that error should be coped with differently).

Comment: so in my case linear  seems better  right?

Comment: Definitely yes. You must look at the plot every time, to have a feeling of what the regression function would be. In your case it's very likely that you will get a 99%+ correlation coefficient.